# Rails internationalization need precision about format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm starting to use I18n in Rails, and I've got 2 questions:
Here is a small example that group both question:

```
en:
  format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
fr: 
  errors:&errors 
    format:Le %{attribute} %{message}
```

The first question is what mean " ! " in the first translation.
The seconde one is how use the format translation. If I get an error, in french, the error format will be '%{attribute} %{message}' and "Le" will not appear nowhere.

I looked in rails guide, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks for the help

Steph.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` at the beginning is some syntactic sugar for YAML (basically because your string starts with a character that should be escaped : `%`.

Note that your French translation will work for rails 3+, if you're using 2.3, you need this :

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      full_messages:
        format: "Le %{attribute} %{message}"
```